# What is Risk Parity?

Tags: stock-markets, volatility

Just heard this term used on TV. It seemed to be referring to some sort of automation.  How does risk parity stabilize/flatten the markets?

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I was not the DV, but I'll say, you offer no context or attempt to explain the origin of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Risk parity is allocation of investments based on risk, rather than asset class, in order to maintain returns while lowering risk. [Investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/risk-parity.asp).